# Tabs like in Safari with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, uikit, swiftui

I'm planning an app, that offers the possibility, to handle itself multiple times in tabs. In other words: Imagine, that the app starts with tab1 and it shows the main screen. You can work as normal. Then you wanna check something in the app somewhere else, but you want to keep your work as it is, so you open a new tab und start navigating to the point you want to. Then you can switch back to tab1 or again to tab2 and everything will remain in these tabs. So it means I want to have multiple instances of the app in different tabs (as you would open a website several times in a tabbed browser).

Is this possible in iOS and if yes, how could I do that with SwiftUI? Would be perfect, if it looks like the tabs in Safari on macOS or iPadOS.

Comment: There is a GitHub repo doing exactly this: https://github.com/QuynhNguyen/SlidingTabView

Comment: Thanks for that hint, but that's not what I am searching for. The repo you are linking to just have several tabs and then it will update the selectedIndex. Unfortunately there is no example coming with, that will show how to change (and save) views while clicking on a tab.

Comment: Did you ever find something to create and reorder tab's like in the finder?

Comment: Actually I had to code everything by myself using `NSTabViewController` but still some things are missing like reordering tabs.